# Error while trying to test AnimatedVectorDrawable, "Can't morph from x to z"

Tags: android, xml, animation, svg, material-design

I wanted to make an AnimatedVectorDrawable, so that my FAB can look atleast somewhat as fabulous as [this one](https://plus.google.com/+NickButcher/posts/ZSUY9ZgirDf), with animations and stuff.

I found [this great tutorial](http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/10/first-look-at-animated-vector-drawable.html), on how to use & implement them etc, and later on I found [a very usefull tool](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/) for converting SVG's into Android-VectorDrawables, and converted these two images:
https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/content/svg/design/ic_add_48px.svg
https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/action/svg/design/ic_done_48px.svg

Now this is the xml-"code" that I've come up with:

***drawable/vector_add.xml:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="48"
    android:viewportHeight="48">

    <group>
        <path
            android:pathData="M0 0h48v48h-48Z" />
        <path
            android:name="add"
            android:fillColor="#ffffff"
            android:pathData="M38 26h-12v12h-4v-12h-12v-4h12v-12h4v12h12v7Z" />
    </group>
</vector>
```

***anim/add_to_done.xml:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="3000"
        android:propertyName="pathData"
        android:valueFrom="M38 26h-12v12h-4v-12h-12v-4h12v-12h4v12h12v7Z"
        android:valueTo="M18 32.34l-8.34-8.34-2.83 2.83 11.17 11.17 24-24-2.83-2.83Z"
        android:valueType="pathType" />
</set>
```

***drawable/ic_add.xml:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/vector_add">

    <target
        android:name="add"
        android:animation="@anim/anim_plus_to_done" />

</animated-vector>
```

If I run this code, I just end up with this error:

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3 Can't morph from M38 26h-12v12h-4v-12h-12v-4h12v-12h4v12h12v4Z to M18 32.34l-8.34-8.34-2.83 2.83 11.17 11.17 24-24-2.83-2.83Z
        at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.setupAnimatorForPath(AnimatorInflater.java:337)
        at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.parseAnimatorFromTypeArray(AnimatorInflater.java:283)
        at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(AnimatorInflater.java:618)
        at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.loadObjectAnimator(AnimatorInflater.java:577)
        at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.createAnimatorFromXml(AnimatorInflater.java:529)
        at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.createAnimatorFromXml(AnimatorInflater.java:542
```

My guess would be that the two path's in the two svg's are too different, so Android cannot handle the animation on it's own, and I need to make like several VectorDrawables for each animation "checkpoint".

...I'm probably completly way off with that theory, but it's the most logical I can come up with..

I do not have much experience (nor any experince at all for that matter) working with Vectors & Illustrator etc, so any help you guys can come up with will be extremely appreciated.

Have a nice day, 
and Merry Christmas.

Sincerely, 
Måns.

Comment: Read this carefully https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable.html "Here is the path_morph.xml, which will morph the path from one shape to the other. Note that the paths must be compatible for morphing. In more details, the paths should have exact same length of commands , and exact same length of parameters for each commands."

Comment: @pskink Thank you sir. I did not understand a word of that though, but now I got it clear for me that I'm too dumb for these kind of things.

Comment: Its easy if you have command "l" (line) in first path you gotta have it in the second path as well and with the same number of parameters (they of course can differ to make the animation happen)

Comment: @pskink okey, I think I understand, thank you sir. But how can I make either the plus- or the done-icon to have same amount of commands as the other? :) And thanks again bro :)

Comment: "+" is made up from two lines, right? "√" or "✓" too ;)

Comment: for example: "+" is "M 2,8 14,8 M 8,2 8,14" and "✓" is "M 2,8 6,14 M 6,14 14,4" (not tested on the device, just taken from inkscape)

Comment: @pskink but svg with just M will not draw anything... or it will?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The VectorDrawables you wish to morph must be compatible, meaning they must have simlar complexities; similar length and number of commands (this was mentioned by pksink).

This way I ended up solving this is taking the "plus" symbol and modifying is the dimensions manually in android studio until I had something that resembled a checkmark.

Plus Vector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp">

    <group android:name="plus_group" android:pivotX="12" android:pivotY="12">
        <path
            android:name="plus_path"
            android:strokeColor="@android:color/white"
            android:strokeWidth="3"
            android:pathData="M12,0L12,24M0,12,L24,12" />
    </group>
</vector>
```

CheckMark Vector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp">
    <group android:name="check_group"
        android:pivotX="12"
        android:translateX="0"
        android:pivotY="12">

        <path
            android:name="check_path"
            android:strokeColor="@android:color/white"
            android:strokeWidth="3"
            android:pathData="M20,0L06,20M0,14,L08,19" />
    </group>
</vector>
```

Notice that these have the same number of commands. The checkmark does not look perfect, but you cannot notice if you put it in a floating action button.

**Additional tip:** Move the pathData to a string variable. That way, it's easier to maintain consistency in your objectAnimators.

Comment: For complex shapes with dozens of instructions, how are we supposed to make them compatible though ?  
Is there any tool allowing to make 2 paths compatible in a sane way (ie show from & to pathes and let you manipulate them)

Comment: I have the perfect paths. They are perfectly equal to the icons provided in the Material Design page. Plus path: M12,5 L12,19 M5,12 L19,12 (stroke width = 2). Done path: M20.3,6.3 L8.3,18.3 M4.1,12.7 L9.7,18.3 (stroke width = 1.98, but you could use 2)

Answer (score 29):

If you want **to morph between arbitrary SVG images (or `VectorDrawable`) you need to align the corresponding paths in order to make them compatible for morphing**.
This is a very tedious task, but there's a command line tool that can do that for you: [**VectAling**](https://github.com/bonnyfone/vectalign)

You just need to run the *VectAlign* tool from the command line passing your original paths and it will automatically create "morphable" sequences.

**Example of usage:**

```
java -jar  vectalign.jar --start "M 10,20..." --end "M 30,30..."
```

**Output:**

```
--------------------
  ALIGNMENT RESULT  
-------------------- 
# new START sequence:  
M 48.0,54.0 L 31.0,42.0 L 15.0,54.0 L 21.0,35.0 L 6.0,23.0 L 25.0,23.0 L 25.0,23.0 L 25.0,23.0 L 25.0,23.0 L 32.0,4.0 L 40.0,23.0 L 58.0,23.0 L 42.0,35.0 L 48.0,54.0 

# new END sequence:  
M 48.0,54.0 L 48.0,54.0 L 48.0,54.0 L 48.0,54.0 L 31.0,54.0 L 15.0,54.0 L 10.0,35.0 L 6.0,23.0 L 25.0,10.0 L 32.0,4.0 L 40.0,10.0 L 58.0,23.0 L 54.0,35.0 L 48.0,54.0
```

Now you can use these new sequences in your Android project and morph between them as usual using an `AnimatedVectorDrawable`!

You can also pass **SVG files**:

```
java -jar  vectalign.jar --start image1.svg --end image2.svg
```

This is one of the samples from the *VectAlign* [demo](https://github.com/bonnyfone/vectalign-samples/):

[image]

Comment: The alignment is very random though.
The transition between two simple SVGs looks very wrong with this kind of tool which makes the 2 paths match randomly.